# Output Title of Post's Current Category

Tags: categories, templates, title

How do I output the current category title for each specific post?

```
            <?php query_posts('category_name=group&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : $counter = 0; ?>
                   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    

                <div <?php if($wp_query->current_post % 2 == 0) post_class('clearfix'); else post_class('clearfix last'); ?>>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>

                    <span class="title"><em>CHILD CATEGORY TITLE HERE</em></span>

                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>

                   <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest answer I could find so far:

$category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]-> cat_name;

Comment: If this is what you are looking for then your question title is really misleading. its just the "category associated with that post" and it has nothing to do with child categories. child categories means that you have a parent category. Anyway glad you got what you need

Comment: Maybe my title was a bit misleading - My bad. It should have said "If a post is a child category - how can I output the child category title"?

Comment: Again, posts don't have child categories, only categories associated. only a category can have a child category just like Pages can have child pages, but posts will never have child categories.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each post has only one child category then:

```
$parent_category_id = 12;
 <?php query_posts('category_name=group&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
 <?php if (have_posts()) : $counter = 0; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
        <div <?php if($wp_query->current_post % 2 == 0) post_class('clearfix'); else post_class('clearfix last'); ?>>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
            <?php
            $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
            $cats = '';

            foreach($post_categories as $c){
                $cat = get_category($c);
                if ($cat->category_parent = $parent_category_id){
                    $cats = $cat->name;
                }
            }?>
            <span class="title"><em><?php echo $cats; ?></em></span>
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and just update "$parent_category_id = 12;" with the real ID of group category.

Comment: Would that output a single category name or multiple child category names (if there were multiple child cats associated)? Thanks!

Comment: only one , and it must be a child of what ever you define at $parent_category_id = 12;

Comment: There should be an easier way to say "Show this post's child category title" .. when each post will only be assigned one child category. No?